# why my application is running only when ob_start() method is used

Tags: php

I have written a simple application which has login page. After login search insertion buttons are there. I build this simple application and run successfully last month. But now when i am using this now my pages are not redirecting to next page. i double checked my syntax.

i googled for the answer and found ob_start() method. And now my application is running successfully.

when the first time i have used this application i didn't use ob_start. But why its not working now without the ob_start(); method.

Please explain.

Search function :

```
            $email = $_POST['search'];
    $sql = "select * from employee_details where ";
    if($email){
    $sql .= " email = '$email' ";
    }

    $rv = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rv) == 0){
    $errmsg_arr[] = "Employee records are not found.";
    $page = "HomePage.php";
    $errflag = true;    
    errors($page,$errmsg_arr, $errflag );
    }
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rv)){
     $var['employee_id'] = $row['employee_id'];
     $var['employeename'] = $row['employee_name'];
     $var['email'] = $row['email'];
     $var['phone'] = $row['phone'];
     $var['address1'] = $row['address1'];
     $var['state'] = $row['state'];
     $var['country'] = $row['country'];
    }
    addvars($var);
    header("location: EmployeeDetails.php");
```

addvars function:

```
function addvars($vars) {
    session_start();
$_SESSION[] = array();  

    foreach($vars as $keys => $vals) {  

$_SESSION[$keys] = $vals;   

}
 }
```

Errors Function:

```
function errors($page,$errmsg_arr, $errflag){
if($errflag) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: $page");
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: We need code. The ob_* functions buffer the output of the page. Depending on your usages this may cause problems. Make sure you arent sending any content before the headers are sent.

Comment: My crystal ball is out of order today. I can't see your code myself, you'll have to be bothered and share it :(

Comment: you guys should put more effort into your crystal balls maintenance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely because you try to set headers when they're already sent out. (you can try to adjust output buffering instead of using `ob_start` if it bothers you).

Comment: hm really made a silly mistake. Actually i manually configured php, apache, mysql, and turned output_buffering to "off" in php.ini file. Now changed the value and its working fine. thanks a lot for your responses.